# Laravel/SQL: return rows where column Equals NOT 'something" and NULL

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

LARAVEL 5.4 (but probably it's a more general SQL question)

Hello! I have a table with a structure:

[image]

Suppose it's my model 'Table'.

**I want a query which:**

uses (receives) variables :

**$id** of array  ['id', 'string', integer]

*where string is '<' or '>'*

**$status_not_bad** = bool;

*(if true - include all rows where 'status' !== 'bad' AND 'status' IS NULL);*

for example, we are given:

```
$id = ['id', '>', 0];

$status_not_bad = true;

Table::thisquery() ... ->get();
```

**"get rows where status is not bad and id > 0" returns rows 1 and 3.**

but if we given:

```
$id = ['id', '<', 3];

$status_not_bad = true;

Table::thisquery() ... ->get();
```

**"get rows where status is not bad and id < 3" returns row 1**

(it should be same query which return those results using those variables).

Answer (score 1):

Just chain your `->where()` clauses. Maybe also consider wrapping them to prevent conflicting with any additional:

```
$results = Table::where("id", ">" 0)
->orWhere("number", ">", 2)
->orWhereNull("status")
->get();
```

Or, wrapped:

```
$results = Table::where(function($query){
  $query->where("id", ">" 0)
  ->orWhere("number", ">", 2)
  ->orWhereNull("status");
})->get();
```

If you want to see what the actual query you're executing is, replace `->get()` with `->toSql()`, and use `dd($result);`:

```
$results = Table::where(...)->toSql();
dd($results);
```

Edit: Sounds like we need multiple wrapping queries, due to multiple conditions:

```
$results = Table::where(function($query){
  $query->where("status", "!=", "bad")
  ->where("id", "<", 3); -- "status is not bad and id < 3"
})->orWhere(function($query){
  $query->where("status", "!=", "bad")
  ->where("id", ">", 0); -- "status is not bad and id > 0"
})->get();
```

That should handle paired conditions as noted in your comment.

Comment: Hi, Tim! no, that's not what i want... I want a query which for "get rows where status is not bad and id < 3" will return row 1 and for "get rows where status is not bad and id > 0" will return rows 1 and 3. (it should be same query).

Comment: Ok, so chain some wrapping `->where`/`->orWhere` queries. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Tim, thank you) probably I have explained my question wrong. I am going to re-write it now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883807/laravel-sql-where-column-equals-not-something-and-null

Comment: Why'd you post a new question? You should have just edited this one. That new on is likely to get closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: hm, I wanted more people to view it. I wanted to delete this one but it was impossible...

Answer (score 1):

I've never used laravel before so my syntax could be off, but I know you want to use MySQL's ifNull function for this:

```
Table::where([['id', '>', 0], ['number', '>', 2])->whereRaw("IfNull(status, 'blah') <> 'bad'")->get();
```