# Laravel/SQL: where column Equals NOT and NULL

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

LARAVEL 5.4 (but probably it's a more general SQL question)

Hello! I have a table with a structure:

[image]

Suppose it's my model 'Table'.

**I want a query which:**

uses (receives) variables :

**$id** of array  ['id', 'string', integer]

*where string is '<' or '>'*

**$status_not_bad** = bool;

*(if true - include all rows where 'status' !== 'bad' AND 'status' IS NULL);*

for example, we are given:

```
$id = [['id', '>', 0]];

$status_not_bad = true;

Table::thisquery() ... ->get();
```

**"get rows where status is not bad and id > 0" returns rows 1 and 3.**

but if we given:

```
$id = [['id', '<', 3]];

$status_not_bad = true;

Table::thisquery() ... ->get();
```

**"get rows where status is not bad and id < 3" returns row 1**

(it should be same query which return those results using those variables).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you end with something like this:

```
if ($status_not_bad) {
    $nStatus = 'bad';
} else {
    $nStatus = 'good';
}

Table::thisquery()->where('status', '<>', $nStatus)
                  ->whereNotNull('status')
                  ->where($id[0], $id[1], $id[2])
                  ->get();
```

But it would be a good idea to check $id keys first.

Comment: doesn't work. if id > 0 ans $status_not_bad = true it returns only row # 1. But should return row 3 as well...

Comment: This query will never return the NULL rows. What would be the rule about returning NULL rows?

Comment: could you be more specific/

Comment: I did not understand when it must return or when must not return objects with NULL status.

Answer (score 1):

Since row `id` = 3 you need `<=` in your where statement to have that row included in the result set

```
$id = ['id', '<=', 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I this works:

```
$chain = Sample::when($status_not_bad, function($query){

   return $query->where('status', '<>', 'bad')
               ->orwhereNull('status');

})

 ->where([$id])
 ->get();
```